# I want to embed a javascript in html as quotes displayer with control of next and previous anchor tags

Tags: javascript, refresh, hyperlink, anchor

I used the following code.

```
<a href="" onclick="previous(); return false;">Previous</a>
```

Problem is that it displays everything right but whenever I click on Previous,it disappears and shows the result and doesn't come back. It does only with refresh.
I have tried same with images, they also disappear showing the result.
Can anyone help me how to display both the quote and previous anchor tag and the same remains after the click on previous?

Example:

> The greatest crimes are caused by surfeit,  not by want.  ~Aristotle
>
> Previous                      Next

I click on previous, it should show previous quote.

Comment: We need to see more code, specifically the html markup around the quote, and the javascript function `previous()`

Comment: I really dont understand your question ... but why is `return false;` in there ?

Comment: Here is a javascript code..,

'<script language="javascript">
function previous()
{
var days = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
var k = Math.round(Math.random()*(days.length-1));
var news = days[k-1];
document.write('<p>' + news + '</p>');
}
</script>' 


and  html code is here:

'<a href="" onclick="previous(); return false;">Previous</a> '

@ManseUK
I saw somewhere on net about above line,, I don't know how return false works in this line and show I include it or not?
Actually I'm a newbie in JS, so sorry for any inconvenience!! And thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering the value of href would solve this! 
example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="previous(); return false;">Previous</a>
```

Mostly it works.